# PIL: draw text spreading color outside

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create an image with some text using Python `Pil` library. But the problem is generated text having spots around the character. How can I remove that? (Black spots will be clearly visible if you move the screen little backwards.)

This is my code :

```
font_size=14
font = ImageFont.truetype(MEDIA_FONT, font_size)

box_image_height = 80
box_image_width = 250

box_image = Image.new(
                    'RGB',
                    (box_image_width, box_image_height),
                    (255,255,255)
                 )

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(box_image)
draw.text((30, box_image_height-34),contact_no , font=font, fill="green")
```

Output:

[image: generated image link]

Comment: I think the problem comes from saving the image as a JPEG, because it's a lossy image format. Can you try to save it as a PNG file?

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier thanks. lemme try

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier thanks its working. but i have some doubt. if i save a jpeg or jpg image as png , then will it lose its clarity

Comment: Yes, I assumed the problem is the image format (lossy compression), however in your code doesn't appear the Image.save() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing box_image to the following might fix it, the 'RGBA' parameter instead of 'RGB' adds the possibility for transparency in the image, and will make the image a png image instead of a jpg image.

```
box_image = Image.new(
                    'RGBA',
                    (box_image_width, box_image_height),
                    (255,255,255)
                 )
```

If you want the text to be smoother, you can make the image 3x as wide, and 3x as high, then add this code to resize it to the original size.

```
img_resized = image.resize((YOURWIDTH/3, YOURHEIGHT/3), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```